# Issues getting multiple PSCustomObject's to export properly in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am try to export out 8 objects in `[PSCustomObect]` to a csv. It only sorta works.

The data is organized nicely in the viewer.

[image]

But the actual CSV export is a mess. Every RegEx match (PSCustomerObject) is a new line instead of being one line per device (Rather, one line per foreach loop object)

[image]

What am I missing here?

```
$content = Get-Content -Path "U:\Dump\dump.nmap"-RAW
#$RegX_splitter = '(?m)(?=^Nmap scan report for )'
$RegX_DeviceIP = '(?sm)Nmap scan report for\s*(?<DeviceIP>.*?)$'
$RegX_DeviceType = '(?sm)Device type:\s*(?<DeviceType>.*?)$'
$RegX_OS = '(?sm)Running:\s*(?<OS>.*?)$'
$RegX_OSdetails = '(?sm)OS details:\s*(?<OSdetails>.*?)$'
$RegX_Servicesplit='(?sm)(?=^23\/tcp)(?<port>\d+\/\w+)\s+(?<state>\w*?)\s+(?<service>\w*?)\s+(?<description>.*?)$'
$counter = 0

$data = $content -split 'TRACEROUTE' | ForEach-Object{

    $counter = $counter + 1
    write-host "============================================="
    write-host $counter
    write-host "============================================="

    if ($_ -match $RegX_DeviceIP){
        write-host 'The Device Name (IP) is:'$Matches.DeviceIP
    }
    if ($_ -match $RegX_Servicesplit){
        write-host 'The port number is:'$Matches.Port
        write-host 'The port is:'$Matches.State
        write-host 'The service running is:'$Matches.Service
        write-host 'The Service description is:'$Matches.Description
    }
    if ($_ -match $RegX_DeviceType){
        write-host 'The Device Type is:'$Matches.DeviceType
    }
    if ($_ -match $RegX_OS){
        write-host 'The OS is:'$Matches.OS
    }
    if ($_ -match $RegX_OSdetails){
        write-host 'The OS details are:'$Matches.OSdetails
    }     
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        DeviceIP = $Matches.DeviceIP
        Port = $Matches.Port
        State = $Matches.State
        Service = $Matches.Service
        Description = $Matches.Description
        DeviceType= $Matches.DeviceType
        OS = $Matches.OS
        OSdetails = $Matches.OSdetails
     }

}

$data | Export-Csv "U:\Dump\testexport.csv" -NoTypeInformation
$data | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

**SAMPLE INPUT**

```
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.1
Host is up (0.000060s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE    VERSION
23/tcp   open  telnet     SMC SMC2870W Wireless Ethernet Bridge
80/tcp   open  tcpwrapped
| http-auth: 
| HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\x0D
|_  Basic realm=GatewayAdmin
|_http-title: Site doesn't have a title (text/html).
5060/tcp open  sip        (SIP end point; Status: 200 OK)
| fingerprint-strings: 
|   SIPOptions: 
|     SIP/2.0 200 OK
|     Content-Type:application/sdp
|     Supported:replaces,100rel,timer
|     Allow:INVITE,ACK,OPTIONS,BYE,CANCEL,REGISTER,INFO,PRACK,REFER,NOTIFY
|     From:<sip:nm@nm>;tag=root
|     To:<sip:nm2@nm2>;tag=4EFF32463135364101C48D67
|     Call-ID:50000
|     CSeq:42 OPTIONS
|     Server:PBX-IP Media Gateway/2.1
|     Via:SIP/2.0/TCP nm;branch=foo;received=10.0.232.59
|_    Content-Length:0
1 service unrecognized despite returning data. If you know the service/version, please submit the following fingerprint at https://nmap.org/cgi-bin/submit.cgi?new-service :
SF-Port5060-TCP:V=7.80%I=7%D=8/28%Time=5D669285%P=i686-pc-windows-windows%
SF:r(SIPOptions,168,"SIP/2\.0\x20200\x20OK\r\nContent-Type:application/sdp
SF:\r\nSupported:replaces,100rel,timer\r\nAllow:INVITE,ACK,OPTIONS,BYE,CAN
SF:CEL,REGISTER,INFO,PRACK,REFER,NOTIFY\r\nFrom:<sip:nm@nm>;tag=root\r\nTo
SF::<sip:nm2@nm2>;tag=4EFF32463135364101C48D67\r\nCall-ID:50000\r\nCSeq:42
SF:\x20OPTIONS\r\nServer:PBX-IP\x20Media\x20Gateway/2\.1\r\nVia:SIP/2\.0/T
SF:CP\x20nm;branch=foo;received=10\.0\.232\.59\r\nContent-Length:0\r\n\r\n
SF:");
Device type: VoIP phone
Running: Aastra embedded
OS details: Aastra Dialog 4425 IP phone
Network Distance: 4 hops
Service Info: Device: bridge

TRACEROUTE (using port 22/tcp)
HOP RTT     ADDRESS
1   0.00 ms 10.X.X.254
2   0.00 ms 10.X.X.73
3   0.00 ms 10.X.X.1
4   0.00 ms 10.X.X.13
```

Comment: what is `$data`'s type before exporting? `$data.getType()`?

Comment: Not sure I understand. I've written other similar scripts where I just call $data at the same moment I create my foreach loop.

Comment: Since you're mixing in a ton of `Write-Host`'s my guess it's either a big string array or a here-string. Your output isn't a PSCustomObject, so it's not going to get pipelined into export-csv with each item in your PSCustomObject's properties being a value in a single column.

I don't have nmap on my work machine but will take a look at home, can't view i.stack.imgur here either

Comment: It adds each of the PSCustomObject's as a value in the csv, it's just that EACH one is a new line in the CSV. I'd want each match in the ForEach loop to be in a single row. All the data is there under the proper column, it's just that the rows are all over the place.

Comment: Gotcha thanks for that. I'll look at this in a few hours

Answer (score 0):

A user on another forum helped me figure it out.

My updated code is below, and worked exactly the way I expected it to.

```
$content = Get-Content -Path "U:\Dump\dumdump.nmap"-RAW
#$RegX_splitter = '(?m)(?=^Nmap scan report for )'
$RegX_DeviceIP = '(?sm)Nmap scan report for\s*(?<DeviceIP>.*?)$'
$RegX_DeviceType = '(?sm)Device type:\s*(?<DeviceType>.*?)$'
$RegX_OS = '(?sm)Running:\s*(?<OS>.*?)$'
$RegX_OSdetails = '(?sm)OS details:\s*(?<OSdetails>.*?)$'
$RegX_Servicesplit='(?sm)(?=^23\/tcp)(?<port>\d+\/\w+)\s+(?<state>\w*?)\s+(?<service>\w*?)\s+(?<description>.*?)$'
$counter = 0

$data = $content -split 'TRACEROUTE' | ForEach-Object{

    $ht = @{
        DeviceIP = ''
        Port = ''
        State = ''
        Service = ''
        Description = ''
        DeviceType= ''
        OS = ''
        OSdetails = ''
    }

    $counter = $counter + 1
    write-host "============================================="
    write-host $counter
    write-host "============================================="

    if ($_ -match $RegX_DeviceIP){
        write-host 'The Device Name (IP) is:'$Matches.DeviceIP
        $ht.DeviceIP = $Matches.DeviceIP
    }
    if ($_ -match $RegX_Servicesplit){
        write-host 'The port number is:'$Matches.Port
        write-host 'The port is:'$Matches.State
        write-host 'The service running is:'$Matches.Service
        write-host 'The Service description is:'$Matches.Description
        $ht.Port = $Matches.Port
        $ht.State = $Matches.State
        $ht.Service = $Matches.Service
        $ht.Description = $Matches.Description
    }
    if ($_ -match $RegX_DeviceType){
        write-host 'The Device Type is:'$Matches.DeviceType
        $ht.DeviceType = $Matches.DeviceType
    }
    if ($_ -match $RegX_OS){
        write-host 'The OS is:'$Matches.OS
        $ht.OS = $Matches.OS
    }
    if ($_ -match $RegX_OSdetails){
        write-host 'The OS details are:'$Matches.OSdetails
        $ht.OSdetails = $Matches.OSdetails
    }     
      [PSCustomObject]$ht

} | Export-Csv "U:\Dump\test.csv"
```